# strpos URL 2 different positions?

Tags: php

lets say the URL is:
http://test.com/site.php?show=1

to get the 1 after = i have done this:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$last_url = substr($url, strrpos($url, '=') + 1);
```

What if i want to get the number 1 and the number after the ? (557)
http://test.com/site.php?show=1?557

How do i do that?

Comment: First of all, you may want to use the `QUERY_STRING` instead. Secondly, you can get away with `strpos`, but a regular expression may be easier here.

Comment: Are you sure that sign "?" is before 557? Correct url should be like: http://test.com/site.php?show=1&somethnig=557

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the fact that $_GET['show'] would be a much easier way.

```
$url = "http://test.com/site.php?show=1?557"
$show = substr(strstr($url, '='), 1);
// $show = '1?557'
// same as: $show = $_GET['show'];
// Approach 1:
$pos = strpos($show, '?');
$first = substr($show, 0, $pos);
$second = substr($show, $pos + 1);
// Approach 2
list($first, $second) = explode('?', $show);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about looping the `$_GET` array?

```
foreach($_GET as $name => $value) {
      $$name = $value;
}
```

This in your example would give you

```
$show = 1
```

It would assign all such `GET` parameters.

Demo: https://eval.in/473464

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions to extract all numbers in url.

```
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $url, $matches);
```

In above code $matches gives you the all numbers in url. 
If you want to match numbers immediately after every `?` Then use `/\?\d+/`

Comment: Please format your answers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks